# `pipreqs` generating blank requirements.txt in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker

I am using Python in a Jupyter Lab notebook in a Docker container. I have the following code in one cell:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
```

Then I run the following cell:

```
!pipreqs /app/loaded_reqs
```

and get:

```
INFO: Successfully saved requirements file in /app/loaded_reqs/requirements.txt
```

But when I open the `requirements.txt`, it shows up empty/blank. I expected `numpy`, `os` and `pandas` to be in this `requirements.txt` file. Why might it not be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Medium post by Iván Lengyel](https://medium.com/@ivalengy/pipreqsnb-pipreqs-with-jupyter-notebook-support-931dc3cf9330), `pipreqs` doesn't support Jupyter notebooks. ([This issue in in the pipreqs repo, open since 2016](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/51) convinces me of the veracity of that assertion. Nicely, [the issue post also suggests](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/51#issuecomment-1200454447) the solution I had already found when searching the terms 'pipreqs jupyter' at Google.) **Plus, importantly** you generally don't use tools that act on notebook files inside the notebook you are trying to use. (Or at least it is something to always watch out for, [or test if possible], similar in a way to avoiding iterating on a list you are modifying in the loop.)

**Solution** -- use `pipreqsnb` instead:
In [that Medium post](https://medium.com/@ivalengy/pipreqsnb-pipreqs-with-jupyter-notebook-support-931dc3cf9330) saying it doesn't work with notebooks, Iván Lengyel proffers a wrapper for it that works for notebooks. So in the terminal outside the notebook, but in the same environment (inside the docker container, in your case), install `pipreqsnb` via `pip install pipreqsnb`. Then run it pointing it at your specific notebook file. I'll give an example in the next paragraph.

I just tried it and it worked in temporary sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) by pressing `launch binder` badge there. When the session came up, I opened a terminal and ran `pip install pipreqsnb` and then `pipreqsnb index.ipynb`. That first time I saw `requirements.txt` get made with details on the versions of `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `scipy`, and `seaborn`. To fully test it was working, I opened `index.ipynb` in the running session and added a cell with `import pandas as pd` typed in it and saved the notebook. Then I shutdown the kernel and over in the terminal ran, `pipreqsnb index.ipynb`. When I re-examined the `requirements.txt` file now `pandas` has been added with details about the versions.

---

More about maybe why `!pipreqs /app/loaded_reqs` failed:
I had the idea that maybe you needed to save the notebook first after adding the import statements cell? However, nevermind. That still won't help because as stated [here](https://medium.com/@ivalengy/pipreqsnb-pipreqs-with-jupyter-notebook-support-931dc3cf9330) `pipreqs`, and further confirmed [at the pipreqs issues list](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/51) doesn't support Jupyter notebooks.
Also, keep in mind the use of the exclamation in a notebook to run a command in the shell doesn't mean that shell will be in the same environment as the kernel of the notebook, see the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) to more perspective on that. (This can be useful to understand for future things though, such as why you want to use the `%pip` or `%conda` magic commands when installing from inside a notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez), and not put an exclamation point in front of that command in modern Jupyter.)

---

Or inside the notebook at the end, I'd suggest trying `%watermark --iversions`, see [watermark](https://github.com/rasbt/watermark). And then making some code to generate the `requirements.txt` from that. (Also, I had seen there was bug in that related to some packages imported with `from X import Y`, see [here](https://github.com/rasbt/watermark/issues/77).)

Or I'd suggest trying `%pip freeze` inside the notebook for the full environment information. Not just what the file needs, though.