# How can list all packages etc. that are actually used in my env/code

Tags: pip, package, anaconda, environment

I usually create a new envirnoment in conda for every new project I work on. Lats time I created a yml-File from my envirnoment. This I have to share with others so they can easily run my code. I noticed two problems:

1. I installed packages with pip (could install with conda-forge)
2. Somehow the envirnoment includes packages I dont need and never used for my code.

I am not really sure if I did something wrong in the beginning but I am very confused why I have so many packages in the yaml that I dont need.
So I would like to look up which packages i actually use in my jupyter lab/Code. Do you know how I can look it up?

```
name: BachelorThesis
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - anyio=3.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - aom=3.5.0=h63175ca_0
  - argon2-cffi=21.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - argon2-cffi-bindings=21.2.0=py310he2412df_2
  - asttokens=2.0.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=22.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
  - babel=2.10.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - backports=1.0=py_2
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.11.1=pyha770c72_0
  - bleach=5.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - boost-cpp=1.78.0=h9f4b32c_1
  - brotli=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py310he2412df_1004
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h8ffe710_4
  - ca-certificates=2022.9.24=h5b45459_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hd694305_1014
  - camelot-py=0.10.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - certifi=2022.9.24=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py310hcbf9ad4_0
  - chardet=5.0.0=py310h5588dad_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.1.3=py310h5588dad_0
  - colorama=0.4.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - contourpy=1.0.5=py310h232114e_0
  - cryptography=37.0.1=py310h21b164f_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - debugpy=1.6.3=py310h8a704f9_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py_1001
  - executing=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - expat=2.4.9=h1537add_0
  - ffmpeg=4.4.2=gpl_h952562b_108
  - flit-core=3.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono=2.37=hab24e00_0
  - font-ttf-inconsolata=3.000=h77eed37_0
  - font-ttf-source-code-pro=2.038=h77eed37_0
  - font-ttf-ubuntu=0.83=hab24e00_0
  - fontconfig=2.14.0=h720f74d_1
  - fonts-conda-ecosystem=1=0
  - fonts-conda-forge=1=0
  - fonttools=4.37.4=py310h8d17308_0
  - freeglut=3.2.2=h0e60522_1
  - freetype=2.12.1=h546665d_0
  - gettext=0.21.1=h5728263_0
  - glib=2.74.0=h12be248_0
  - glib-tools=2.74.0=h12be248_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.20.3=h001b923_2
  - gstreamer=1.20.3=h6b5321d_2
  - icu=70.1=h0e60522_0
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=4.11.4=py310h5588dad_0
  - importlib_resources=5.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - intel-openmp=2022.1.0=h57928b3_3787
  - ipykernel=6.16.0=pyh025b116_0
  - ipython=8.5.0=pyh08f2357_1
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - ipywidgets=8.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jasper=2.0.33=h77af90b_0
  - jedi=0.18.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jpeg=9e=h8ffe710_2
  - json5=0.9.5=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - jsonschema=4.16.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py310h5588dad_7
  - jupyter_client=7.3.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_console=6.4.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=4.11.1=py310h5588dad_0
  - jupyter_server=1.21.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab=3.4.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_server=2.16.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - kiwisolver=1.4.4=py310h476a331_0
  - krb5=1.19.3=h1176d77_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h2a16943_0
  - lerc=4.0.0=h63175ca_0
  - libblas=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - libcblas=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - libclang=14.0.6=default_hf4acfee_0
  - libclang13=14.0.6=default_h8992b79_0
  - libcurl=7.85.0=heaf79c2_0
  - libdeflate=1.14=hcfcfb64_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=h8ffe710_5
  - libglib=2.74.0=h79619a9_0
  - libiconv=1.17=h8ffe710_0
  - liblapack=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - liblapacke=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - libogg=1.3.4=h8ffe710_1
  - libopencv=4.6.0=py310hb1fdf93_4
  - libpng=1.6.38=h19919ed_0
  - libprotobuf=3.21.7=h12be248_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h8d14728_1
  - libsqlite=3.39.3=hcfcfb64_0
  - libssh2=1.10.0=h680486a_3
  - libtiff=4.4.0=h8e97e67_4
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=h0e60522_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h8ffe710_0
  - libxcb=1.13=hcd874cb_1004
  - libxml2=2.9.14=hf5bbc77_4
  - libxslt=1.1.35=h34f844d_0
  - libzlib=1.2.12=hcfcfb64_3
  - lxml=4.9.1=py310he2412df_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py310he2412df_1
  - matplotlib-base=3.6.1=py310h51140c5_0
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mistune=2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mkl=2022.1.0=h6a75c08_874
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - munkres=1.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - nbclassic=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbclient=0.6.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert=7.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-core=7.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-pandoc=7.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbformat=5.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - notebook=6.4.12=pyha770c72_0
  - notebook-shim=0.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - numpy=1.23.3=py310h4a8f9c9_0
  - opcua=0.98.13=py310h5588dad_2
  - opencv=4.6.0=py310h5588dad_4
  - openh264=2.3.1=h63175ca_1
  - openjpeg=2.5.0=hc9384bd_1
  - openpyxl=3.0.10=py310h8d17308_1
  - openssl=1.1.1q=h8ffe710_0
  - packaging=21.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandas=1.5.0=py310h1c4a608_0
  - pandoc=2.19.2=h57928b3_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pcre2=10.37=hdfff0fc_1
  - pdfminer.six=20220524=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - pdftopng=0.2.3=py310h984467d_3
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pillow=9.2.0=py310h52929f7_2
  - pip=22.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pixman=0.40.0=h8ffe710_0
  - pkgutil-resolve-name=1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ply=3.11=py_1
  - poppler=22.04.0=hb57f792_3
  - poppler-data=0.4.11=hd8ed1ab_0
  - prometheus_client=0.14.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.31=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.31=hd8ed1ab_0
  - psutil=5.9.2=py310h8d17308_0
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=hcd874cb_1001
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - py-opencv=4.6.0=py310hbbfc1a7_4
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycryptodome=3.15.0=py310he2412df_0
  - pygments=2.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pypdf2=2.10.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyqt=5.15.7=py310h1fd54f2_1
  - pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py310h00ffb61_1
  - pyrsistent=0.18.1=py310he2412df_1
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyh0701188_6
  - python=3.10.6=h9a09f29_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.10=2_cp310
  - pytz=2022.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pywin32=303=py310he2412df_0
  - pywinpty=2.0.8=py310h00ffb61_0
  - pyzmq=24.0.1=py310hcd737a0_0
  - qt-main=5.15.6=hf0cf448_0
  - qtconsole=5.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtconsole-base=5.3.2=pyha770c72_0
  - qtpy=2.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests=2.28.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - send2trash=1.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - setuptools=65.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - sip=6.7.2=py310h00ffb61_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - sniffio=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - soupsieve=2.3.2.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.39.3=hcfcfb64_0
  - stack_data=0.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - svt-av1=1.2.1=h0e60522_0
  - tabulate=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - tbb=2021.6.0=h91493d7_0
  - terminado=0.15.0=py310h5588dad_0
  - tinycss2=1.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h8ffe710_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.2=py310he2412df_0
  - traitlets=5.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.3.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2022c=h191b570_0
  - ucrt=10.0.20348.0=h57928b3_0
  - unicodedata2=14.0.0=py310he2412df_1
  - urllib3=1.26.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vc=14.2=hb210afc_7
  - vs2015_runtime=14.29.30139=h890b9b1_7
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py_1
  - websocket-client=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - widgetsnbextension=4.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py310h5588dad_4
  - winpty=0.4.3=4
  - x264=1!164.3095=h8ffe710_2
  - x265=3.5=h2d74725_3
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.9=hcd874cb_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=hcd874cb_0
  - xz=5.2.6=h8d14728_0
  - zeromq=4.3.4=h0e60522_1
  - zipp=3.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.12=hcfcfb64_3
  - zstd=1.5.2=h7755175_4
  - pip:
    - docopt==0.6.2
    - ghostscript==0.7
    - natsort==8.3.1
    - osc4py3==1.0.8
    - pipreqs==0.4.13
    - pyads==3.3.9
    - yarg==0.1.9
prefix: C:\Users\Rebecka A\anaconda3\envs\BachelorThesis
```

So what I want to do is uninstall all the dependencies I dont need. For example I know that I dont need qtpy etc....

An then I want to reinstall the USED pip Packages eg. ghostscript and natsort.

Comment: try to create the yml file with `--from-history`

Answer (score 0):

Point things at the code you are using **in the `.ipynb` files** while in the environment to have it look for what gets import.

- [pipreqsnb](https://github.com/ivanlen/pipreqsnb) (See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75356319/8508004) that discusses using pipreqsnb that will make a `requirements.txt` noting what get's import in the notebook cook)
- [watermark - An IPython magic extension for printing date and time stamps, version numbers, and hardware information](https://github.com/rasbt/watermark). (Note that [for a while some using 'from X import Y' fail to show from watermark for now](https://github.com/rasbt/watermark/issues/77).)
- [iversions](https://github.com/iamaziz/iversions)